# Determine if a set is linearly independent or dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $S = \{r,u,d\}$ and $S$ is a set of linearly independent vectors.
and if $x = r + 4u + 2d$, determine whether $T = \{r,u,x\}$ is a linearly independent set as well.
Not sure how to go about solving this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are scalars $\;a,b,c\;$ s.t.

$$0=ar+bu+cx=ar+bu+c(r+4u+2d)=(a+c)r+(b+4c)u+2cd=0$$

But you know $\;\{r,u,c\}\;$ (some choice of letters!) is lin. ind., so then

$$a+c=0\;,\;\;b+4c=0\;,\;\;2c=0$$

Take it from here (and  yes: the new set is lin. indp. too)

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of the application which maps $S$ onto $T$ is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&4&2\end{array}\right)$$
whose determinant is $2\neq0$.

So $T$ is linearly independent, too.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start supposing
$$ar+bu+cx=0$$
with $a,b,c$ scalars and use that $x=\cdots$ and that $S$ is l.i.